# What is the wrong in extend from an activity with view model?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, mvvm, viewmodel

i create BaseActivity calss and all other activities extends from this class,
and BaseViewModel class and all other view models extents from it.
the questions are .
1- what is the wrong if i make the BaseViewModel the BaseActivity's view model ?(note that every activity has its own view model )
2- if nothing is wron ,do this process affect the performence?

thanks.

Comment: why would you want to have the same VM and base activity for everything though ? would you rather not take the recommended approach of a single activity with fragments

Comment: in the base activity i implement the progress bar and the api errors dialog and these features are common in all activities , for this i made th base activity